# Formatted flash drive in Linux, now it won't show

Tags: usb-flash-drive

A few weeks ago I formatted my 16GB PNY flash drive following some guide online regarding formatting flash drives in linux as I've never done that before. I'm running xubuntu.

The format seemed to ruin the device. It won't pick up in Windows or Linux. I stuck it the usb just now and ran $ df and it doesn't appear to be there.

Any advice on this or did I break it?

Thanks :)

Comment: What command did you use to format it? What is the output of `sfdisk -d /dev/device` and `file -s /dev/device`? Does it show up in `dmesg` once you insert it?

Comment: nothing comes up. It cannot open it it says